# returning rows depending on input criteria in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting 2 arrays from the database, in both of the arrays there is a capital_payment which is 80 in both of them. So what I am trying to accomplish is that, the user gives a input which I get from $amount, of 90 , then I only select the row which has  less than 90 , if the user selects 160 or 160+ i return both the rows, if the user selects 159 I return only one row . So that is basically the criteria I need to work with. I am trying to return the data in a array depending on the criteria. But I am making to many mistakes so need help.

```
public function GetSellLoanData($token, $amount, $expirationDate, $radioChecked, $orig_id)
{
    $result =  $this->investment->getLoansBorrowedData($id, $orig_id);
    $foo = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);
    $amountTemp = 0;
    $data = array();
    foreach($foo as $investment)
    {
        //check if input Amount greater than $AmountTemp from for each loop
        if($amount > $amountTemp)
        {
            $data[] = $investment;      

            //DO a check to see what happens to the array data
            foreach($data[] as $check){

            }
            // see if the new array did not exceed the $amount 

            //adding rows here
            $data[] = $investment;

            }else{
                break;
            }
            $amountTemp += $investment['capital_payment'];
        }
      return $data;
    }
}
```

And also I want to return all the other information in the array selected so I guess my $data array is not right as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made some new changes! Hope this works!

```
 $amountTemp = 0;
 $data = array();
 foreach($foo as $investment)
 {
     //check if input Amount greater than $AmountTemp from for each loop
     if($amount > $amountTemp + $investment['capital_payment'])
     {
          $data[] = $investment;      
     }else{
                break;
          }
      $amountTemp += $investment['capital_payment'];
  }
```

Comment: Sorry tried it, but did not work, if I write 90, it still adds 2 array , but should be adding 1